# pagespeed_optimize_image.exe returning worse results than Google Page Speed Extension

Tags: image, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, image-optimization

Why is pagespeed_optimize_image.exe from http://page-speed.googlecode.com/files/pagespeed_optimize_image.exe returning worse compression than Google Page Speed Extension? For some of the images it is worse for even about 10 %. 
Is there a way to return exact the same files as in Google Page Speed Extension in bulk in Windows 7 as it is possible with pagespeed_optimize_image.exe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, I got my answer at [Google Page Speed Service Discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/page-speed-service-discuss/cpPkMKGInwU)

> (about pagespeed_optimize_image.exe)(...) it's pretty outdated.  It's not related to PageSpeed Service at all, which uses a different image optimization stack.  We would like to release a binary to statically optimize your images, but we just haven't been able to prioritize it.
>   You can kind of get that today by running an Apache server locally with mod_pagespeed installed and pointing at your image directory.  Then you can optimize any image you want by running 'wget' to that server. Joshua Marantz